# Cannot access network folder without IP Address

Tags: networking, windows-10, nas

I have recently installed Windows 10 but somehow cannot access the shared network drives using the hostname. I have to use IP address in order to access it. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: As mentioned in Chico's answer, this is probably a DNS problem.  Please edit the question to say : By "Shared Network" do you mean "Shared Network Drive"?  Is this a home network or a work network?  Do all of the PCs involved have network visibility turned on?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I've just edited it. It is home network and yes all the PCs have the network visibility turned on.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the shared folder using the hostname you need to have a DNS server up and running, some home routers automatically provide this function and some ones not, if you just installed Windows 10 chances are that IPV6 is enabled and your DNS server does not support it

try disabling ip6 in the control panel, also you can check how is your name resolved using the following command in the console window nslookup (hostname)

if there is a DNS responding it will appear on the response window along with the hosname ip address

More info can be found here: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/using-nslookup/